# Castle windsor to use a fakeiteasy object while Resolving in Unit test

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, mocking, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I am very noob in both FakeItEasy and Castle Windsor and that is why i am having problem even in searching Google as i don't know the keywords to search for.

Now coming to the problem

I am having a class

```
public class PersonService : IPersonService
{
    IMarriageHelper objIMarriageHelper;
    IPersonRepository objIPersonRepository;
    public PersonService(IMarriageHelper objMarriageHelper, IPersonRepository objPersonRepository)
    {
        this.objIMarriageHelper = objMarriageHelper;
        this.objIPersonRepository = objPersonRepository;
    }

}
```

Now I am using Castle Windsor to resolve my PersonService class in unit test case.

```
        var objContainer = new WindsorContainer();
        objContainer.Register(Component.For<PersonService>());
        objContainer.Register(Component.For<IMarriageHelper>().ImplementedBy<MarriageHelper>());
        objContainer.Register(Component.For<IPersonRepository>().ImplementedBy<PersonRepository>());
        var objPersonService = objContainer.Resolve<PersonService>();
```

Now the problem is I want to send fake object of PersonRepository while resolving PersonService but not MarraigeHelper.

Pleas help me out with this as I am very new to this.

Comment: You may try [autofixture](https://github.com/AutoFixture) too - it is very good for the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In castle windsor, when you register multiple component to the same interface will make Windsor to resolve the first one or the one that was marked with Default().

There are many ways to solve your issue. I'm going to point only few of them...

Registerion using Name:

```
const string FAKE_REPOSITORY = "fake person repo";
var fakePersonRepository = A.Fake<IPersonRepository>();
objContainer.Register(Component.For<IPersonRepository>()
                               .Instance(fakePersonRepository)
                               .Named(FAKE_REPOSITORY));
const string PERSON_FOR_TEST = "person for test";
objContainer.Register(Component.For<PersonService>()
                               .DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent(typeof(IPersonRepository), FAKE_REPOSITORY))
                               .Named(PERSON_FOR_TEST));
```

And the resolve this the person service:

```
var target = objContainer.Resolve<PersonService>(PERSON_FOR_TEST);
```

Another option is to make your `PersonService` dependson [dynamic parameters](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/how-dependencies-are-resolved.md)
In this scenario you resolve `PersonService` with `fakePersonRepository`

```
var target = objContainer.Resolve<PersonService>(<key name>, fakePersonRepository)
```

I can think about 3-4 more options(factory methods, some combination between those methods and etc...) however, I think the best way to build `PersonService` for test is to build it explicitly without using windsor magic/use windsor only for resolving `IMarriageHelper`.
Then your code will be much more readable and easy to maintain.

Comment: thanks a lot the explanation. I will right away implement the code and see how that works. One more request , can you specify the name or some key words of other 3-4 way so that i can Google it and  know about those ways.

Comment: Of course: [Factory method](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/registering-components-one-by-one.md) allows you to create a custom creation method. [Factory facility](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/typed-factory-facility-interface-based.md) very similar to Factory method. Create [Installer](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/README.md) for tests, which allows you to override the settings... the last one is: you can the any combination between the options...